# DataError: No numeric types to aggregate when using groupby and rank

Tags: python, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe like this:
[Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DfMyN.jpg)

Each number appears multiple times in the dataframe with different create date, and I want to rank the numbers by their create dates like this example:

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZbzG.jpg)

I used groupby with rank and got this error:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPZSe.jpg)

Comment: I think it's an error because the data type is a string type. `column_name.astype(int)`

Comment: I converted the create date column to datetime and it worked!